# Properly transpose Pandas dataframe and access first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I read from a csv file, looks like this:

```
original = pd.read_csv("fruit.csv")

print(original)
      fruit  apple  banana  pear
0    weight     50      45    48
1     price    100     150   200
2  calories     10      50    40
```

I would like to transpose it so that I can access the categories that are now in the 'fruit' row as their own colums, i.e. like this:

```
print(transposed['fruit'])

0  apple
1  banana
2  pear
```

Such that I can do things like `print(transposed[transposed['fruit']=='apple']['weight'])`

If I try to simply transpose the dataframe then I cannot access the first column (`KeyError: 'fruit'`). I tried all sort of manipulations of the dataframe, but either the index gets messed up or the first column name gets deleted (when I `reset_index()`, 'fruit' becomes 'index' for some reason).

Comment: you shouldnt `transposed[transposed['fruit']=='apple']['weight']` but using loc is better `transposed.loc[transposed['fruit']=='apple', 'weight']`. why? if you do `transposed[transposed['fruit']=='apple']['weight'] = 99` you can see a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `fruit` as the index; selection should be much easier:

```py
temp =  df.set_index('fruit')
temp.loc['weight', 'apple']
50
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it provides a useful solution in the spirit of my original use case. As well, there appears to not be a simple way to transpose a dataframe and keep the index column without doing some magical incantations that the other solutions propose.

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt` and `pivot`:

```
>>> df.melt('fruit').pivot('variable', 'fruit', 'value') \
      .rename_axis(index='fruit', columns=None).reset_index()

    fruit  calories  price  weight
0   apple        10    100      50
1  banana        50    150      45
2    pear        40    200      48
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
transposed = df.T.reset_index().set_axis(df.T.reset_index().iloc[0], axis=1).iloc[1:].rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> transposed
    fruit weight price calories
1   apple     50   100       10
2  banana     45   150       50
3    pear     48   200       40

>>> transposed[transposed['fruit']=='apple']['weight']
1    50
Name: weight, dtype: object
```